# How to modify makefile for openMP inclusion

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, openmp

HI everybody I am a beginner for both openMP and makefile. Here is my problem.

I usually compile simple openMP code via terminale using:

> g++-10 -o file.exe -fopenmp file.cxx

Now I want to modify a code, which consists in many file linked together, adding openMP libraries. Indeed I have to change the already existing makefile and I have no idea how to do it. The openMP libraries are used only in the file "esercizio1.1.cxx".

Here the makefile:

```
esercizio1.1 : esercizio1.1.o random.o
g++ -o esercizio1.1 esercizio1.1.o random.o 

esercizio1.1.o : esercizio1.1.cxx funzioni.h random.h
g++ -c -o esercizio1.1.o esercizio1.1.cxx 

random.o : random.cxx random.h
g++ -c -o random.o random.cxx

clean:
rm esercizio1.1
```

Here an example of how I tried to modify my makefile. I renamed my file and I added

- g++-10 -fopenmp

to all the line at the same time, to all the line one per time. but still does not work. Here an example:

```
esercizio : esercizio.o random.o
g++-10 -fopenmp esercizio.o random.o -o esercizio

esercizio.o : esercizio.cc funzioni.h random.h
g++-10 -fopenmp esercizio.cc -o esercizio.o

random.o : random.cc random.h
g++ random.cc -o random.o

clean:
rm esercizio
```

Here is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN6Random6RannyuEv", referenced from:
      _main._omp_fn.0 in ccA635Wn.o
  "__ZN6Random8SaveSeedEv", referenced from:
      _main in ccA635Wn.o
  "__ZN6Random9SetRandomEPiii", referenced from:
      _main in ccA635Wn.o
  "__ZN6RandomC1Ev", referenced from:
      _main in ccA635Wn.o
  "__ZN6RandomD1Ev", referenced from:
      _main in ccA635Wn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [esercizio.o] Error 1
```

Does it exist a guide for makefile beginner?

Anyway I would appreciate if someone helped me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add `-fopenmp` to the first two invocations of `g++`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hristo. I already tried but does not work. I tried to add -fopenmp to the first invocation of g++, to the second and both at the same time. Does not work.

Comment: OK, please be more specific about what does not work.  Please add a full error output of the g++ compiler to your post to receive further help.

Comment: @MichaelKlemm ok thanks I did it.

Comment: C++ compilers are picky and may come with different ABIs, thus mixing different C++ compilers in the same project isn't advised. You are compiling `random.cc` with `g++`, which on macOS is a symlink to Apple's `clang++`. Use `g++-10` instead.

Comment: Also, `g++ -o random.o random.cc` produces an executable file, not an object file. Leave it as `g++-10 -c -o random.o random.cc`.

Comment: thank you so much @HristoIliev. I owe you a beer :) This solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

"C++ compilers are picky and may come with different ABIs, thus mixing different C++ compilers in the same project isn't advised. You are compiling random.cc with g++, which on macOS is a symlink to Apple's clang++. Use g++-10 instead. Also, g++ -o random.o random.cc produces an executable file, not an object file. Leave it as g++-10 -c -o random.o random.cc."

credits to Hristo Iliev. Thank you.